# How to build this regex to perform replacements of each of the elements of a list within a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, python-re

```py
import re

list_to_find = [['1', '00', 'am'], ['1', '00', 'pm'], ['1', '', 'pm'], ['', '', 'pm'], ['5', '', 'pm']]
list_corrected = [['01', '00', 'am'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['01', '00', 'pm'], ['00', '00', 'am'], ['05', '00', 'pm']]

input_text = "el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 01:00 am 01:00 pm, : p m, 1: pm  5  pm"


n=0
for elem_to_find in list_to_find:

    #civil_time_pattern = r'(\d{1,2})[\s|:]*(\d{0,2})\s*(am|pm)?'
    civil_time_pattern = str(elem_to_find[0]) + r"[\s|:]*" + str(elem_to_find[1]) + r"\s*" + str(elem_to_find[2])
    civil_time_pattern_fix = ( str(list_corrected[n][0]) + ":" + str(list_corrected[n][1]) + " " + str(list_corrected[n][2]) ).strip()
    print(repr(civil_time_pattern))
    print(repr(civil_time_pattern_fix))

    input_text = re.sub(civil_time_pattern, civil_time_pattern_fix, input_text, 1) #I set only one replacement per iteration in order from left to right

    n += 1

print(repr(input_text))
```

This is the **incorrect output** that the program is returning

```py
'1[\\s|:]*00\\s*am'
'01:00 am'
'1[\\s|:]*00\\s*pm'
'01:00 pm'
'1[\\s|:]*\\s*pm'
'01:00 pm'
'[\\s|:]*\\s*pm'
'00:00 am'
'5[\\s|:]*\\s*pm'
'05:00 pm'
'el cine esta abierto hasta 23:3000:00 am o 001:00 am, 01:00 am 001:00 pm, : p m, 01:00 pm  05:00 pm'
```

And this would be the correct output that I am needing

```py
'el cine esta abierto hasta 23:30 pm o 01:00 am, 01:00 am 01:00 pm, 00:00 p m, 01:00 pm  5:00 pm'
```

I think the problem is in this regex, and since it can't find the elements correctly, it repeats them and some ignores them because it doesn't find a match. How should I fix this code?

```
civil_time_pattern = str(elem_to_find[0]) + r"[\s|:]*" + str(elem_to_find[1]) + r"\s*" + str(elem_to_find[2])
```

Comment: You need to change the approach. Match the substrings of your choice, parse them and then replace with the necessary format.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just leave this regex in the code, `civil_time_pattern = r'(\d{1,2})[\s|:]*(\d{0,2})\s*(am|pm)?'` , but it is precisely with it that I was able to extract the elements of the string `input_text` and store this elements in a list called `list_to_find`  with a `re.findall(civil_time_pattern, input_text)` method. I don't know if you mean that? or if this regex pattern that I passed you will really help for this case?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok thank you very much, you would help me a lot.

Comment: Sorry, too busy. But you got the gist.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ohh don't worry, yesterday in the night I edited this question **limiting the number of replacements to 1 for each iteration of the for loop**, and the result obtained improved substantially. I think that in this case the only thing that fails is the regex. Personally, I never work with regex that are updated within a loop taking elements from a list, maybe that's why I feel it's a complex problem, but broadly speaking it's nothing more than **changing this RegEx** `str(elem_to_find[0]) + r"[\s|:]*" + str(elem_to_find[1]) + r"\s*" + str(elem_to_find[2]) ` **for another RegEx**

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not very human readable, and therefore is prone to errors and confusion. That's why the PRegEx package was created, to help resolve some of this confusion. See their [GitHub](https://github.com/manoss96/pregex), [Docs](https://pregex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pregex/) for info.

Also, this blog is quite helpful to help you understand how to use it: [PRegEx: Write Human-Readable Regular Expressions in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/pregex-write-human-readable-regular-expressions-in-python-9c87d1b1335).

Comment: Thanks, I'll read that medium article, the problem is that precisely this replacement of lists, where the regex pattern criteria changes as a for loop progresses, is really quite complex, at least for me (and I've been I've been trying to do it for a while, but I'm stuck )